# Best way to apply multiple (string) cleaning functions to a large pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a few large pandas dataframes (300+ columns and about 114M rows, each). Most of the columns are string, and have some issues in them, like requiring the use of `trim`, or conversion to Sentence case, removal of escaped characters (like `\n`), etc. Currently, my workflow to clean up involves:

1. A function (`clean_up`), which applies the required cleaning functions to each value in the passed column.
2. `clean_up` also checks whether the column is not `object` type, and returns unedited column if it is not `object`.
3. An `dataframe.apply` that calls `clean_up`.

As you can imagine, it takes forever for this code to run. The only idea I have is to split the task of step 3 above to run on multiple processes (as the processing of each column is independent of the others), and stitch the dataframe back together at the end (say by using `dask`). Does anyone know of a better way to do this?

Comment: Could you post a sample dataset along with the code you currently use?!

Comment: Without your current code and sample data it's hard to know where to optimize, and what's already good.

Comment: Fundamentally, `pandas`/`numpy` cannot work efficiently with strings. You should probably clean the strings using vanilla python data-structures. I'm assuming your data is serialized as csv?

Comment: I cannot post any of the dataset (trust me, I would if I could). And fabricating some would be not conducive to the question as I cannot faithfully recreate the messy strings. I am seeking to brainstorm ideas. I mean, if you had a dataset with messy stings in many columns and rows, and you wanted a method of accessing them to apply a set of functions with as small time complexity as possible, how would you do it? I don't know how vanilla python would help as well, because that requires loops too. The data are in accdb and sas files.